# Unable to get data through fetch into context

Tags: reactjs

I have a context for a simple site that I want to load via fetch on page load. I created the context and provider:

```js
const ResumeContext = createContext<ResumeJson | undefined>(undefined);

export function useResumeContext() {
    const context = useContext(ResumeContext);
    return context;
}

function ResumeLoader({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    let resume = useResumeContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getResumeJson() {
            const response = await fetch("resume.json");
            const data: ResumeJson = await response.json();
            return data;
        }

        getResumeJson().then((data) => {
            resume = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return <Fragment></Fragment>;
}

export default function ResumeContextProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    return (
        <ResumeContext.Provider value={undefined}>
            <ResumeLoader />
            {children}
        </ResumeContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And then set it in the base of my app, in the `index.tsx`:

```js
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ResumeContextProvider>
            <App />
        </ResumeContextProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I see the data loaded by the fetch, but in the App component, when I use the `useResumeContext`, the value never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the context value with the fetched data. You should maintain the resume data in a state within `ResumeContextProvider` and update that state when the fetch completes. Here's a corrected version:

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState, PropsWithChildren, Fragment } from 'react';

const ResumeContext = createContext<ResumeJson | undefined>(undefined);

export function useResumeContext() {
    const context = useContext(ResumeContext);
    return context;
}

function ResumeLoader({ setResume }: { setResume: (resume: ResumeJson) => void }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getResumeJson() {
            const response = await fetch("resume.json");
            const data: ResumeJson = await response.json();
            return data;
        }

        getResumeJson().then((data) => {
            setResume(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }, [setResume]);

    return <Fragment></Fragment>;
}

export default function ResumeContextProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    const [resume, setResume] = useState<ResumeJson | undefined>(undefined);

    return (
        <ResumeContext.Provider value={resume}>
            <ResumeLoader setResume={setResume} />
            {children}
        </ResumeContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Note that I added a `setResume` prop to `ResumeLoader` and wrapped the resume in a state within `ResumeContextProvider`. Now, when `getResumeJson` fetches the data, it will update the state, and any components using `useResumeContext` will re-render with the new data.

Comment: Of course, that worked, heh. I had something very similar in the previous iteration, and I'm not sure why this worked and that didn't. More to learn!